# My if statement is not recognizing string.indexOf(letter) == -1

Tags: typescript

```
export default class Pangram {
    private input: string;
    private alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    constructor(input: string) {
        this.input = input.toLowerCase();
    }

    isPangram(): boolean {
        if(this.input.length == 0) return false;

        this.alphabet.split('').forEach(letter => {
            console.log(this.input.indexOf('x')); // console => -1
            if(this.input.indexOf(letter) == -1) {
                return false
            }
        });

        return true;
    }
}

const pangram = new Pangram("a quick movement of the enemy will jeopardize five gunboats");
console.log(pangram.isPangram());
```

The console log is returning -1, but the if the statement is not capturing that -1, and so the function is returning `true` when it should be returning `false`, any ideas why?

The test case is testing for a missing x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that `return false` affects only the scope of your `forEach` function, not the `isPangram`. In fact, I've even tried it on typescript playground and got compilation error because of not all paths of `forEach` return value.

I suspect you've wanted something similar to below

```
private isXFound = true;
isPangram(): boolean {
    if(this.input.length == 0) return false;

    this.alphabet.split('').forEach(letter => {
        console.log(this.input.indexOf('x')); // console => -1
        if(this.input.indexOf(letter) == -1) {
            this.isXFound = false;
        }            
    });

    return this.isXFound;
}
```

Comment: Also add a `return;` after setting `this.isXFound = false` in order to break out of the `forEach`. No need to continue checking since the result should be false as soon as any letter of the alphabet is not present in the input string.

Comment: @MattU `return;` does not break the foreach loop.

Comment: @Evert you're right. Sorry, I was thinking of traditional `for` loops.

Answer (score 0):

Even easier is to just not use `.forEach`, which imho should be the default for most uses anyway:

```
    for (const letter of this.alphabet.split('')) {
      if(this.input.indexOf(letter) == -1) {
        return false
      }
    };

    return true;
```

You could also use `every` for this, which will also exit as soon as it finds the first negative:

```
    return this.alphabet.split('').every( letter => {
       return this.input.indexOf(letter) !== -1;
    });
```

Comment: @Pegasus18 Curious to learn more about the downvotes! Maybe I'm missing something, but each of these solutions are far simpler and higher performance than the workaround with `forEach()`

Comment: I didn't downvote, thanks for your answer. I'm going to stick with forEach in my case as it's purely for an exercise not production.